# Multiple conditions in a "If" algorithm

Tags: algorithms

I've done a lot of searching in google but not found any answer to my question.
I'm searching for a way to write this in latex :

> if ( (t<-3) || ((s>4)&&(t<3)&&(tendency>-3)) ) {do some action...}

I didn't manage to find a latex command to write properly those || and &&.

Comment: Welcome, packages like `algorithm` might be of help for future algorithms. FOr now, `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\parallel$ \&
\end{document}
`

Comment: really appreciate the quick reply ! it works ! thanks !

Comment: @Johannes_B An answer maybe?

Comment: @percusse `\parallel` was the first thing that came to my mind. Is there a etter alternative?

Comment: @Johannes_B I think minted or algorithmicx and that sort allow you to type directly without a fake,