# Using algorithm2e, how to make IF condition 1 OR conditions 2 OR conditions 3 THEN

Tags: algorithm2e, algorithmic

Using `algorithm2e`  currently when I do this

```
\If{ condition_1  OR condition_2 OR condition_3}
```

But if the stuff between `{}` is too long, it wraps around and does not look good since there is no alignment.

I looked at [Multiple conditions in a "If" algorithm](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299942/multiple-conditions-in-a-if-algorithm)  but did not see a solution there.

Is there a way to break each condition on its line, so it show up at end as follows

```
IF condition_1
      OR
   condition_2
      OR
   condition_3  THEN
   ....
END IF
```

Here is a MWE, showing 2 conditions only as an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \DontPrintSemicolon 

    \KwIn{1st order ODE}
    \KwOut{solution}

    \eIf{ A}
    {
       stuff
       \eIf{  B}
       {
          stuff
       }
       {
           \uIf{ condition 1  \textbf{or} condition 2  \textbf{or}  condition 3 }
           {
                stuff
           }
           \uElseIf{ condition 1  \textbf{and} condition 2 \textbf{and} condition 3 }
           {
             stuff
           }
          \ElseIf{  condition 1  \textbf{or} condition 2 \textbf{and} condition 3  }
          {
              stuff
          }
       }
    }
    {
      stuff
    }
    \Return solution

    \caption{my algorithm}

\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Compiled using lualatex, this is the output

[image]

btw, I could not find `\Or` , `\And` in algorithm2e so I am for now using `\textbf{or}` in place.

### Trials

Tried manual fix, which almost works,  like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \DontPrintSemicolon 

    \KwIn{1st order ODE}
    \KwOut{solution}

    \eIf{ A}
    {
       stuff
       \eIf{  B}
       {
          stuff
       }
       {
           \uIf{ condition 1 \; 
                \hspace{30pt}\textbf{or}\; 
                \hspace{15pt} condition 2\; 
                \hspace{30pt}\textbf{or}\;
                \hspace{15pt}condition 3 }
           {
                stuff
           }
           \uElseIf{ condition 1  \textbf{and} condition 2 \textbf{and} condition 3 }
           {
             stuff
           }
          \ElseIf{  condition 1  \textbf{or} condition 2 \textbf{and} condition 3  }
          {
              stuff
          }
       }
    }
    {
      stuff
    }
    \Return solution    
    \caption{my algorithm}    
\end{algorithm}    
\end{document}
```

Which now looks like

[image]

The vertical lines `ruled` now do not look good as not have gaps.

Any better solution to this? I could ofcourse just turn off the vertical lines using `\SetAlgoNoLine` and now it looks OK. But it is nice to have the vertical lines there if possible.

[image]

TL 2020

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not familiar with `algorithm2e` enough, hence the following approach is not perfect. This attempt uses the macros in [`algorithm2e` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf), sec. 11.

#### Small example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\SetKw{Or}{\hspace{\algoskipindent}\itshape or\;}
\SetKw{And}{\hspace{\algoskipindent}\itshape and\;}
\SetKwBlock{Condition}{}{}

\begin{algorithm}
  \DontPrintSemicolon
  \If{condition 1 \Condition{\Or condition 2 \;\Or condition 3 \;\And condition 4}}
  {
    stuff
  } 
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Applied to your example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}

\SetKw{Or}{\hspace{\algoskipindent}\itshape or\;}
\SetKw{And}{\hspace{\algoskipindent}\itshape and\;}
\SetKwBlock{Condition}{}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
    \DontPrintSemicolon 

    \KwIn{1st order ODE}
    \KwOut{solution}

    \eIf{ A}
    {
       stuff
       \eIf{  B}
       {
          stuff
       }
       {
           \uIf{condition 1 \Condition{\Or condition 2 \;\Or condition 3}}
           {
                stuff
           }
           \uElseIf( // the indent is not satisfying){condition 1 \Condition{\And condition 2 \;\And condition 3}}
           {
             stuff
           }
          \ElseIf{\Condition{condition 1  \;\Or condition 2 \;\And condition 3}}
          {
              stuff
          }
       }
    }
    {
      stuff
    }
    \Return solution

    \caption{my algorithm}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]