# algorithm2e - If with multiple conditions and vlined option, preferably with Python style syntax

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

I am trying to use [algorithm2e](https://ctan.dcc.uchile.cl/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf) to write an algorithm which looks like so (made with Latex+Paint):
[image]

Based on [this Stack Exchange answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/548894/141755), I have attempted the following:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled, linesnumbered, vlined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Example algorithm}
\SetKw{And}{and} \SetKw{Not}{not} \SetKw{In}{in}
\SetKwArray{Array}{array} \SetKwData{El}{element}
\SetKwIF{If}{ElseIf}{Else}{if}{:}{else if}{else}{}
\SetKwBlock{Condition}{}{}
\SetKwFor{For}{for}{:}{}
\For{\El \In \Array}{
    \If{condition 1 \And \Condition{
        condition 2 \And \\
        \Not condition 3}}{
            do something with \El\;
       }
}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Which yields:
[image]

The red marker shows the issue.

I then tried changing the syntax to be if-then and for-do while maintaining the `vlined` option, as in the example below

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled, vlined, linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Example algorithm}
\SetKw{And}{and} \SetKw{Not}{not} \SetKw{In}{in}
\SetKwArray{Array}{array} \SetKwData{El}{element}
\SetKwIF{If}{ElseIf}{Else}{if}{then}{else if}{else}{}
\SetKwBlock{Condition}{}{}
\SetKwFor{For}{for}{do}{}
\For{\El \In \Array}{
    \If{condition 1 \And \Condition{
        condition 2 \And \\
        \Not condition 3}}{
            do something with \El\;
       }
}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

which yields
[image]
The problem now is that a `lined` option specifically for the region shown with the red arrow would be better than the desired `vlined` option.

I would prefer a solution for the first example, but a solution for just the second example would still be marked as accepted.

Comment: Come to think of it, first example doesn't make it very clear where the conditions end and the following code starts. The second example would be better after all.